# New table created on every PowerPivot refresh?

Tags: excel, sql-server-2012, sharepoint-2013, powerpivot

My PowerPivot workbook, hosted in Excel Services, has started generating new tables in the PowerPivot data model on refreshes. It's pulling from an Oracle database. And while the refresh says it fails, "Excel services returned an error", but I opened up the workbook to find a dozen tables named, "Query1", "Query2", "Query3" etc.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/cKyAmu9.png]

We're currently using SharePoint 2013 and SQL Server 2012 SP2.

Comment: Are you pulling directly from Oracle through Power Pivot or using Power Query to import the data?

Comment: @mmarie No, but I am pulling from two different SQL Servers and an Oracle database. It's weird, the columns get added when I "Refresh All" locally as well.